# Moving tables and its content to the top and bottom of a bigger cell

Tags: html, css

How can I move the rows titled "border one" and "border two" to the top and bottom of the cell they reside in? If I try padding top/bottom, it messes up the structure upon zooming in/out.

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0uzjyxa5/

```
    <table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="680" height="942" style="border-top: 1px solid white;">

    <td style="width: 288px; height:auto;">

    </td>

    <td>
        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr><td>border top</td></tr>
        </table>

        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr><td>venue info</td></tr>
        </table>

        <table border="1" width="100%">
            <tr><td>border bottom</td></tr>
        </table>
        <td style="width:17px;"></td>
    </td>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can align your table data using

```
table td {
   vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

or

```
table td {
   vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: How can td get both style  bottom & top ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried what you said, but it pushes up all three rows to the top of the cell. I tried adding classes to them but that doesn't work. I only one "border one" and "border two" to be on extreme ends of the cell.

Comment: what do you mean "border one" and "border two" to be on extreme ends of the cell?

Comment: Sorry, I meant border top and bottom (they are in the fiddle). I just want those two to be vertically aligned to top and bottom of the cell, respectively.

Comment: YES! Thank you so much. Can you please explain the `position: relative;` bit you put on the `td-border` class?

Comment: It is used so the absolute position for the child is relative to the parent which is td-border instead of the document window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71235/discussion-between-zerodarkthirty-and-syahrul).